# ¿Cómo validar palabra clave para decodificación en Java?

Tags: java

En este código de cifrado, ¿cómo puedo validar que el usuario ha insertado la palabra clave correcta (ingreseClave) para poder decodificar el texto dado?

```
    if (ingreseTexto.getText().length() < 1) {
        ingreseTexto.setError("No ha ingresado ningún texto");
    } else
        if (ingreseClave.getText().length() < 1) {
            ingreseClave.setError("No ha ingresado ninguna clave");
        } else {
            if (rbCodificar.isChecked()) {

                textoCodificado = Codificar(ingreseTexto, claveLenght);
                textoSalida.setText(textoCodificado);

            } else if (rbDecodificar.isChecked()) {
                textoDecodificado = Decodificar(ingreseTexto, claveLenght);
                textoSalida.setText(textoDecodificado);
            }
        }
```

Por ejemplo, si tenemos:
`ingreseTexto` = Esto es una prueba
`ingreseClave` = test

La salida actual es:

`textoCodificado` = Iwxe iw yre tvyife

Al aplicar la función para decodificar, ¿cómo se valida que `ingreseClave` sea correcta? Es decir, al aplicar la inversa `textoCodificado + ingreseClave` me debería dar el mismo texto de entrada.

El código original es este, pero lo he modificado para no usar JOptionPane, y para aplicar decodificación entrando la palabra clave:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //gets a string to encrypt
    String str = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Data to encrypt:"));

    //gets a key 
    String key = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the key:"));
    int keyLength=key.length();

    //prints encryption
    String encrypted = encrypt(str, keyLength);
    System.out.println("Encrypted:" + encrypted);

    //prints decryption
    String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, keyLength);
    System.out.println("Decrypted:" + decrypted);

    //prints key
    System.out.println("Key:" + key);


}

public static String encrypt(String str, int keyLength) 
{
    String encrypted = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
    {
        int c = str.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) 
        {
            //26 letters of the alphabet so mod by 26
            c = c + (keyLength % 26);
            if (c > 'Z')
            c = c - 26;
        } 
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) 
        {
            c = c + (keyLength % 26);
            if (c > 'z')
            c = c - 26;
        }
        encrypted += (char) c;
    }
return encrypted;
}

public static String decrypt(String str, int keyLength) 
{
    String decrypted = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
    {
        int c = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) 
        {
            c = c - (keyLength % 26);
            if (c < 'A')
            c = c + 26;
        } 
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) 
        {
            c = c - (keyLength % 26);
            if (c < 'a')
            c = c + 26;
        }
        decrypted += (char) c;
    }
    return decrypted;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta. Si vuelves a encriptar la encriptada (usando la misma palabra de paso), te devuelve el texto original, el programa funciona bien... ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: Validar. ¿Cómo verifico que la palabra clave es la que decodifica la frase ya codificada? Es decir, si yo ingreso el texto junto con la palabra clave, y este es codificado, para decodificarlo debo ingresar el texto codificado más la palabra clave. ¿Cómo se valida la palabra clave? Si la palabra clave es incorrecta, se debe mostrar un mensaje: 'Palabra clave incorrecta'.

Comment: De la misma manera que te he dicho en el comentario anterior: si encriptas la encriptada (la frase ilegible) usando la misma clave, te debe dar la palabra original. ¿Prefieres que te lo desarrolle en forma de código Java?

Comment: He intentado de esa manera, pero cuando ejecuto, simplemente me dice 'Clave inválida' aún cuando es la correcta. Quizás tu código muestre lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0):

Te he tabulado el código, y te he añadido una modificación hacia el final del main para que veas la comprobación de la clave:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * Clase TextEncryption.
 *
 * @author Antonio A. López Fernández
 * @version 13/09/2017
 */
public class TextEncryption {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //gets a string to encrypt
        String str = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Data to encrypt:"));

        //gets a key 
        String key = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the key:"));
        int keyLength = key.length();

        //prints encryption
        String encrypted = encrypt(str, keyLength);
        System.out.println("Encrypted:" + encrypted);

        //prints decryption
        String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, keyLength);
        System.out.println("Decrypted:" + decrypted);

        /* PRINCIPIO MODIFICACIÓN */
        String reencrypted = encrypt(decrypted, keyLength);
        System.out.printf("Encrypted:" + reencrypted + " (if this is the same as above, everything's going fine)\n");

        if (reencrypted.equals(encrypted)) {
            System.out.printf("Key:%s OK\n", key);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Key:%s KO\n", key);
        }
        /* FIN MODIFICACIÓN */
    }

    public static String encrypt(String str, int keyLength) {
        String encrypted = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int c = str.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                //26 letters of the alphabet so mod by 26
                c = c + (keyLength % 26);
                if (c > 'Z') {
                    c = c - 26;
                }
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                c = c + (keyLength % 26);
                if (c > 'z') {
                    c = c - 26;
                }
            }
            encrypted += (char) c;
        }
        return encrypted;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String str, int keyLength) {
        String decrypted = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int c = str.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                c = c - (keyLength % 26);
                if (c < 'A') {
                    c = c + 26;
                }
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                c = c - (keyLength % 26);
                if (c < 'a') {
                    c = c + 26;
                }
            }
            decrypted += (char) c;
        }
        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Encrypted:Yjcyt xjhwjyt.
Decrypted:Texto secreto.
Encrypted:Yjcyt xjhwjyt. (if this is the same as above, everything's going fine)
Key:llave OK
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la función de "Key:%s KO\n" ?

Comment: Si algo falla al encriptar la encriptada (valga la redundancia), mostrará ese mensaje. Es como decir "clave inválida".